# Google auth - auto sign-in/sign-out between apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth, google-authentication

I have a google chrome extension and a simple web app where I use google Auth to sign in users. How can I make auto sign-in in the web page if I already did that in chrome extension?

Or, how can I auto sign-in chrome extension if I already did the sign-in in the web page. I've seen that Loom has done this kind of functionality between chrome extension and their web app.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Comment: Ok, i have found a solution. Using content script you can do that specific logic

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it to help future readers